# Predicting outcome of multiple targets in SciKit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, analytics

Working on a Classification problem using python scikit, its a medical diagnostics data having 6 features and 2 targets. I tried with one target, trained a model using KNN algorithm, prediction accuracy is 100% with this model.

Now want to extend this to second target, want to predict the outcome of two y values for the same feature set(6 columns).

Following is my code where Im able to accurately predict the outcome of Target 1 ('Outcome1-Urinary-bladder'). How can I extend to predict the outcome of the second Target (Outcome2-Nephritis-of-renal).

```
X = Feature_set
y  = Target1['Outcome1-Urinary-bladder'].values
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X,y)
y_predictor = knn.predict(X)
print metrics.accuracy_score(y,y_predictor)
```

[Click here to view the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxed_8T6OPe4bi1QcDhORlVzejQ/view?usp=sharing)

What modifications to be made to the code to predict outcome of 2 target values ('Outcome1-Urinary-bladder' & Outcome2-Nephritis-of-renal)?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `KNeighborsClassifier` supports multiple outputs.

Comment: Off topic, but you should realize that accuracy ought to be evaluated using cross-validation for meaningful generalization; in your code above you're evaluating your model's performance using the same set you trained on

Comment: In particular, using KNeighborsClassifier with n_neighbors=1 you will always have 100% accuracy on your training set, without learning anything.

Answer (score 0):

In general you just wrap your classifier into one-vs-rest classifier wrapper:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier

And feed it with the matrix y which will have 2 columns at the same time.

Example of usage:

```
selClassifiers = {
    'linear': LinearSVC(),
    'linearWithSGD': SGDClassifier(),
    'rbf': SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True),
    'poly': SVC(kernel='poly', probability=True),
    'sigmoid': SVC(kernel='sigmoid', probability=True),
    'bayes': MultinomialNB()
}

classifier = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(selClassifiers[classif]))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)

predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)

all_labels = lb.inverse_transform(predicted)
```

As pointed by @yangjie, for your specific classifier there is no need to wrap it, it already support multi-output classification.

Comment: There is no need to wrap into `OneVsRestClassifier`.

Comment: Yes - in current case. But if he used different classifier this would have been needed - especially if used with pipeline. Also wrapper gives more control over behavior, giving ability to specify number of jobs. I am talking about general case.